# Yodlee IAV - How to exactly use it?

Tags: java, salesforce, apex, yodlee

I have been searching for it that how to use Yodlee IAV APIs(I am using it on salesforce platform) to verify an account. I am using the same parameters that have been specified in the documentation by the Yodlee but every time it is not returning the expected result.

I am calling `updateItemCredentialsAndStartVerificationDataRequest` and `addItemCredentialsAndStartVerificationDataRequest`. I am using 30 days trial account to explore Yodlee IAV APIs but not able to get how to use them.

While calling updateItemCredentialsAndStartVerificationDataRequest, it throws `InvalidItemException`.

`{"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"com.yodlee.core.InvalidItemException","referenceCode":"_5e6a8e2b-15c4-45d0-b523-6c64a414b274","message":"Argument value not found: 710636"}`

and while calling `addItemCredentialsAndStartVerificationDataRequest` it throws error log.

I also tried [TestDrive](http://developer.yodlee.com/TestDrive) for addItemAndStartVerificationData, it worked there. But when I make this same request using code Apex-Salesforce, giving same params to the Yodlee then it throws this exception.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Errors xmlns="http://namespace.yodlee.com/pfm/2009/Error">
    <Error>
        <errorCode>415</errorCode>
        <errorDetail>system_error</errorDetail>
    </Error>
</Errors>`

**Is there anything which is different in Yodlee IAV documentation than what you exactly used in TestDrive?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying IAV Data services, so you need to first provide credentials to add a bank account and start verification for that particular account.

It would be great if you can first go through IAV data services [flow chart](http://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification_API/IAV_Services_Guide/IAV_API_Flow/IAV_Data_Services_API_Flow) and [quick start](https://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification_API/IAV_Quickstart/IAV_Data_Services_REST_Quick_Start_Guide) to learn more.

Also you can use Yodlee Interactive's [TestDrive](http://developer.yodlee.com/TestDrive) tool which allow you to test the different APIs.

First Login to the Test Drive using your trial credentials and create a user session and then select IAV services. Once you do that you can see an option "Flows" which will guide you to start and test IAV step by step.

For testing it is suggested to use Dummy Account Generator([DAG](http://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/dhaction.do)) accounts which Yodlee provides.
To know more about DAG please click [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Sample_Data/Yodlee_Dummy_Account_Generator).

Comment: Hi Apoorv

I have tried it using test drive but getting the same exception.
/jsonsdk/ExtendedInstantVerificationDataService/updateItemCredentialsAndStartVerificationDataRequest

```
{
    "errorOccurred": "true",
    "exceptionType": "com.yodlee.core.InvalidItemException",
    "referenceCode": "_8e0dd319-42d3-4055-9746-452f9e7ec69d",
    "message": "Argument value not found: 710587"
}
```

Comment: I tried testDrive for addItemAndStartVerificationData, it worked there. But when I make this request using code, giving same params to the Yodlee then it throws exception.


```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Errors xmlns="http://namespace.yodlee.com/pfm/2009/Error">
    <Error>
        <errorCode>415</errorCode>
        <errorDetail>system_error</errorDetail>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

Comment: I have uppdated my question also. Please reply asap. I will follow this post until I am done with its integration and will let you know when done

Comment: Is there anything which is different in Yodlee IAV documentation than what you exactly used in TestDrive?